# Set sort order of MySQL query using dropdown options

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I want to allow site users to change the sort order of results that are returned by an existing query.
The query is currently

```
$searchList = 'select distinct pa.products_id, pd.products_name,
               p.products_model
               FROM ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES . ' pa
               left join ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . ' pd on (pa.products_id = pd.products_id)
               left join ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS . ' p on (pa.products_id = p.products_id)
               WHERE pd.language_id = ' . $language_id . '
               order by products_model';
```

I've added the following code to generate the dropdown

```
<select id = "SortBy">
<option value ="">Please Choose<br>    
<option value ="products_model;">Model (asc)<br>
<option value ="products_model DESC;">Model (desc)<br>
<option value ="products_name;">Name (asc)<br>
<option value ="products_name DESC;">Name (desc)<br>
<option value ="products_id;">Product ID (asc)<br>
<option value ="products_id DESC;">Product ID (desc)
</select>
```

and updated the query to

```
$searchList = 'select distinct pa.products_id, pd.products_name,
               p.products_model
               FROM ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS_ATTRIBUTES . ' pa
               left join ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS_DESCRIPTION . ' pd on (pa.products_id = pd.products_id)
               left join ' . TABLE_PRODUCTS . ' p on (pa.products_id = p.products_id)
               WHERE pd.language_id = ' . $language_id . '
               order by ".mysql_real_escape_string($sort)."';
```

After the select options and before the sql query I've added

```
$sort=$_POST["SortBy"]
```

which i believe should contain the selection made once it's submitted.

This is where I'm a little stuck. I want the user to be able to select their option from the dropdown and have it auto submit and store the choice so that the query which follows uses their selection but I don't know how to do this. I'm assuming some type of jQuery, but to be honest I'm lost when it comes to coding in this.

Following comments from Jeff I have changed the select list to this

```
<select id = "SortBy" name="SortBy>
<option value ="">Please Choose<br>    
<option value ="model+">Model (asc)<br>
<option value ="model-">Model (desc)<br>
<option value ="name+">Name (asc)<br>
<option value ="name-">Name (desc)<br>
<option value ="prodid+">Product ID (asc)<br>
<option value ="prodid-">Product ID (desc)
</select>
```

and added the following code

```
    switch ($_SESSION ['sba_sort_order']) {
    case 'model+' :
        $order_by = ' products_model; ';
        break;
    case 'model-' :
        $order_by = ' products_model DESC; ';
        break;
    case 'name+' :
        $order_by = ' products_name; ';
        break;
    case 'name-' :
        $order_by = ' products_name DESC; ';
        break;
    case 'prodid+' :
        $order_by = ' products_id; ';
        break;
    case 'prodid-' :
        $order_by = ' products_id DESC; ';
        break;
```

Still lost on how to get this to trigger automatically and store the result for the sql query on selection of a dropdown though.

Comment: You are open to an SQL injection!  please stop what you are currently doing to learn the correct way http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: How so? I thought that the purpose of using mysql_real_escape_string was to prevent SQL injection? Please also note that the page where this code is used is a secure admin area that requires username and password to access it. It's not open to general public

Comment: apart from 1st comment: your misstake is, that the select has no `name='SortBy'`. Post values will be called by it's name, not it's id!

Comment: But you should _REALLY_ think about not having plain sql-code as a posted parameter.

Comment: @Jeff So <select id = "SortBy"> should become <select id = "SortBy" name='Sortby'>
Have I understood you correctly there?

Comment: yes. still, please rethink your code-design.

Comment: Even if in this particular case you can ensure that nobody but you uses that page and will never be anywhere on a public server, just learn to do it the right way.

Comment: @Jeff I've updated the question with some additional code that I can use to prevent plain sal code being used as posted parameters

Comment: I'd probably handle the sorting with a bit of javascript, so avoiding additional trips to the database. E.g.: http://www.jeasyui.com/tutorial/datagrid/datagrid8_demo.html

Comment: Although it may solve the particular problem, you still should know how to do a basic ordering based on user input, especially that one day you may need to order by a "non-exposed" column.

Answer (score -1):

First of all if you want some kind of "auto submit" you need to handle the onChange event, so your select could look like the following:

```
<select id = "SortBy" name="SortBy" onchange="submitForm()">
```

jQuery style

```
$("#SortBy" ).change(function() {
   //submit the form
});
```

Of course all kinds of toolkits like Dojo, jQuery and other (you mentioned jQuery - IMO it's always good to use any of them, at least for the cross-browser support) will help you with this.

Also, think about how do you want to post the data to your server:  asynchronously or not.

Have a look at [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) and try to implement it this way. Create a controller which will handle the request (it may also validate it, some prefer validate on the model level), create a model which will save the chosen option if you want it persistent and prepare a view to interact with the user. It may be just "Your choice was successfuly saved", but it really depends on how you actually want it.